# Discord.js: Bot should mention user who did the command

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am making a bot for Discord as a first JS Project who will print out GIFs or Images after the user wrote a !GIF or !JPG command. Additionally it will add a message. **How can i mention the user who made the command in the message above the GIF / Image**? I tried and did search but couldn't find a solution.

```
client.on("message", msg => {

const sentences = ["Here is your sh*", "Take that image and shove it!", "Lol ok..."]
const texts = sentences[Math.floor(Math.random() * sentences.length)];

if (msg.content === "!Commands") {
  msg.reply("Use '!GIF' for random GIFs and '!JPG'for random JPGs");
}

if (msg.content === "!GIF") {  
  gifNumber = 6 
  var randomGif = Math.floor (Math.random() * (gifNumber - 1 + 1)) + 1;
  msg.reply(texts, {files: ["./gif/" + randomGif + ".gif"]}); 
}

if (msg.content ==="!JPG") {
  jpgNumber = 2
  var randomJpg = Math.floor (Math.random() * (jpgNumber - 1 + 1)) + 1;
  msg.reply(texts, {files: ["./jpg/" + randomJpg + ".jpg"]});
}

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `msg.author.id`

```js
msg.channel.send(`<@${msg.author.id}> any text`);
```

Will allow you to mention to user within the same message with the way mentions are made

`<@UserID>` mentions a user

`<#ChannelID>` mentions a channel

`<@&RoleID>` mentions a role

Answer (score 0):

The stringified User object will parse into a mention.
Send 2 messages, 1 for the mention, and the 2nd for the content

```
msg.channel.send(msg.author);
msg.channel.send(texts, {files: ["./jpg/" + randomJpg + ".jpg"]});
```